# easy, programmable data plotting

Tags: macos, plot, data-visualization

I spend most of my time plotting data, but unfortunately I haven't found a decent solution for my plotting needs. At the moment, the most powerful and pleasant library I found that  performs plotting is matplotlib. The results are stunning, but I mostly spend my time fighting with the library when trying to do simple things like having an arrow as I want. SImilar programs like R and gnuplot produce visually less appealing results, and they are not GUI based.

On the other hand, programs like xmgrace (or better) allow direct manipulation of the plotted objects and direct feedback, but they fail on two important points:

1. if my dataset (normally stored in csv files) changes for some reason, I have to reimport it and perform the manipulations again, by hand
2. once I obtain a nice plot setup, the only way I have to recreate the plot is to use a graphical, interactive program. I would like to have the possibility to run a command line utility on my csv files and get the .pdf as a result, with no human intervention.

I still have to find something that provides me both worlds, and it has an affordable price. Ideally, I would need an interactive GUI program (a la Origin) to generate matplotlib-based python scripts.

Does anyone have any hints on software that could address my needs on OSX (preferably) or Linux ?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what kind of interactive editing tool you need.

Comment: Something similar to origin, where you can use direct interaction with the objects you add to the plot, and produce a "script" object I can replay on a different dataset in a non-interactive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out [Igor Pro](http://www.wavemetrics.com/). It's quite old, and quirky but it provides the most advanced plotting system I've found yet on the Mac. You can modify anything graphically, at a command line or in script files. The most powerful feature (IMO) is the ability to automatically generate a script to recreate a figure or to use a figure to create a script that generates figures *like* (in style etc.) a particular figure. I use Igor for all publication figures I produce.

Data is stored in "waves" (translation: vectors) which encapsulate data and information about the delta between data points (e.g. time step). Figures reference waves as their data source. When you update a wave (e.g. by re-importing a CSV file and specifying that the data overwrite specific waves), all figures that reference that wave are automatically updated.

You can create "layouts" which are page-layouts containing multiple graphs. These layouts are also automatically updated whenever any of the figures in the layout are updated (see above). You can add drawing/text/annotations to either graphs or layout.s

Be warned: Igor Pro's scripting language is something like the bastard child of VB and Matlab. It makes my eyes bleed. It makes me pray to whatever God that the pain just end. **But** the entire system is so powerful that it's worth it.

Comment: Right, you made me remember Igor Pro. I saw it in action a long time ago. It was cool, but ancient indeed. I will take a better look at it, and see if it's worth the money.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used Matlab or R for this sort of thing.  While you may not like how the generic plots look, I find that once I familiarize myself with the libraries I can make them as fancy as I want them to be.

R being free, I would try to stick it out with that.  It is extremely powerful and perfectly suited to what you need (generate charts on the fly directly from datafiles).  I bet that the more you get comfortable with it, you'll find yourself using R for a wide range of tasks outside of plotting data.

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is cross-platform GPL library which meet all yours criteria. It can produce nice graphics, it can read csv files, it have window for displaying graphics (you don't need to know widget libraries), and it can plot in console (don't need a window or X at all). At this you can use C/C++/Fortran/Python/... for yours own code or MGL scripts for simplicity (see [UDAV](http://udav.sf.net/) front-end in the last case).

Finally it can produce bitmaps (PNG/JPEG/GIF/...) or vector (EPS/SVG) output. Later it can be converted to PDF easily. Or you can create a PDF with U3D directly -- you'll need HPDF and U3D libraries in this case.